# Outputting data a row at a time from mysql using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to fetch data from a mysql database using sqlalchemy and use the data in a different class.. Basically I fetch a row at a time, use the data, fetch another row, use the data and so on.. I am running into some problem doing this..

Basically, how do I output data a row at a time from mysql data?.. I have looked into all tutorials but they are not helping much.

Comment: -1: No code sample.  No specific error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what problems are you running into?

You can simply iterate over the ResultProxy object:

```
for row in conn_or_sess_or_engine.execute(selectable_obj_or_SQLstring):
   do_something_with(row)
```

Comment: I think this still loads the whole list into memory.  Which with large data sets is bad...

Comment: "I think this still loads the whole list into memory": I do not believe this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're interested in something like this:

```
# s is object returned by the .select() method
rs = s.execute()
row = rs.fetchone()
# do something with the row
row = rs.fetchone()
# do something with another row
```

You can find this in a tutorial [here](http://www.rmunn.com/sqlalchemy-tutorial/tutorial.html).